# Formspree Profanity Filter

Tags: javascript, html

I am using formspree for a contact sheet on my site, and I am wondering if there is a way to use javascript to block profanity from being sent on the sheet, or a way to block specific words at all. The code I have is super basic so far:

> 

```
  <label>
    Your name:
    <input type="name" name="Name">
  </label>
    <label>
      Your email:
      <input type="text" name="Email">
    </label>
    <label>
      Your message:
      <textarea name="message"></textarea>
    </label>
  
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
```

Ideally I would want to be able to block profanity on the Your Message area. I know you can do this on formspree if you have a premium account but I am wondering if there's anyway I can do it within the code. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can make JS code which will work onchange of your message, if last symbol isn't letter (word is finished)read it and if it find some bad word delete it. Also you can use JQuery or write that yourself.

> [Also JQuery word filter](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0520__Regular-Expressions/Badwordfilter.htm)
>
> [Jquery page with that function](http://people.apache.org/%7Egmonroe/wordFilter/)

Answer (score 0):

I gave it a go using Vanilla JavaScript, but I'm not too sure if this is what you wanted. Either way, hope it helps:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<label>
  Your name:
  <input type="name" name="Name">
</label>
<label>
  Your email:
  <input type="text" name="Email">
</label>
<label>
  Your message:
  <textarea id="msg" name="message" ></textarea>
</label>

<button onclick="check()" type="submit">Send</button>

<script>

  function check() {

    const black_list = ["Pineapple Pizza"];

    var description = document.getElementById("msg").value;

    console.log(description);

    let profane = black_list.some(word => description.includes(word));

    console.log(profane);

  }


</script>

</body>
</html>
```